# Camera is not accessable in chrome browser in Iphone-13 using navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia() API

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

I am trying to enabled the Web cam using `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia()` but not able to enabled  camera in Iphone-13 in chrome browser.

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true, video: { width: 2160, height: 3840 } }) .then(async stream => {
           let bh_ = stream.getTracks()[0].getSettings();
                bh_.frameRate, bh_.height, bh_.width

                const camera = new Camera(videoElement, {
                    onFrame: async () => {
                        const d = new Date();
                        let seconds = d.getSeconds();
                        if (c == 0) fp_seconds = seconds;
                        c++;
                        if (seconds - fp_seconds != 0) {
                            fps_text_box.innerHTML = c;
                            c = 0;
                        }
                        await faceMesh.send({ image: videoElement });
                    },
                    width: bh_.width,
                    height: bh_.height,
                });
                camera.start()
            })
```

Comment: you're missing a semi-colon, and the rest of the code.

Comment: above I have mention the code can you help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: Please [edit] your question, or ask another question, and describe your `Camera` class. It isn't part of the `getUserMedia()` subsystem. The same goes for `faceMesh`.